# Constructing a continuous map for an interval with some points of period x, but none of period 3

Tags: polynomials, dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

I was given this question where I have to construct a continuous map f:I -> I (interval) with a point of period 4, but none of period 3. I know that thanks to Sharkovskii's theorem that if it had a point of period 3, it would have a point of any period implying chaos, so this map I need to construct must not be chaotic. I know the function must be such that

$(f)^4$(x) = x, ie => $(f)^4$(x) - x = 0

The only problem is I don't know how to go about constructing a map, any starting tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Divide $I$ into 4 equal parts and make $f$ cyclically permute them. $f(x)=x+1/4\pmod 1$.

Comment: @markvs I'm not sure I follow, so I'd have f(x) = x + 1/4 (mod  1) =x+1/4 and $f^2$(x)=x+1/2 mod 1 = x + 1/2, $f^3$(x)=x+3/4 and $f^4$(x)=x+1 ?

Comment: All sums modulo $1$, so $f(0)=1/4, f^2(0)=1/2, f^3(0)=3/4, f^4(0)=0$, $0$ is a periodic point of period $4$.

Comment: @markvs Wait, this question is that easy, just do a mod for the period I want and that works with any interval? That was very clever idea thanks a lot, I was thinking I'd have to manually make a load of functions to try find period 4 one. The $f^3$(x) = 3/4 shows that there isn't a period of 3, which implies Sharkovskii's theorem isn't applicable here so no chaos too.

Comment: Use the logistic map (or the tent map). Select a parameter in the interval between the second and third period doubling bifurcation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compilation of comments. Define $f(x)=x+1/4 \pmod 1$. It is a continuous function $I\to I$. $f(0)=1/4, f^2(0)=1/2,   f^3(0)=3/4,
 f^4(0)=0$, so $0$ is a periodic point of period $4$. It is easy to see that there are no periodic points of period $3$.